# how to use lambda expression to call method indeed of foreach

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

how can i code this using lambda expression.

```
for(UserLocationEntity locationEntity : userLocationEntities){
                getAddressFromGmap(locationEntity);
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if that is what you want but consider using

```
userLocationEntities.forEach(o -> getAddressFromGmap(o));
```

You can also use

```
userLocationEntities.forEach(this::getAddressFromGmap);
```

or

```
userLocationEntities.forEach(YourClass::getAddressFromGmap);
```

depending on if `getAddressFromGmap` is static or not.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used them as I've not tried Java 8 yet, but a quick search led me to this one:

```
userLocationEntities.forEach(locationEntity -> getAddressFromGmap(locationEntity))
```

Anyways, when posting on StackOverflow you should show some research efforts.

It's not like "*how can I*" but more like "*I've tried this but it's not working, can you help me figuring out what I'm doing wrong?*"